# ERROR! MariaDB server PID file could not be found

Tags: mariadb

After a hard restart on macOS (monitor blacked out) i can't get my mariadb to work.

`ERROR! MariaDB server PID file could not be found! Starting MariaDB .210121 09:45:40 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/computer.local.err'`

Logfile: /usr/local/var/mysql/computer.local.err

```
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.4.11.
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-01-21  9:48:16 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
```

- Mariadb is installed via homebrew
- I have restarted and reinstalled mariadb via homebrew

any ideas how to fix this? :)

---

**Solution**
If found the solution, That is, to remove these `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`. Those logfiles prevented mariadb to start